# What is the valid phone number format accepted by contact-form-7

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

What is correct phone number format supported by contact form 7 telephone field. Is it something like `###-###-##` or `### ### ##` or `########` or `+# #######` or any other ?

I tried searching about the format, but couldn't get any result. I'm trying to implement a client side validation check, for which I need to know format that is applied on server side by contact form 7.

Comment: You can get a quick and great response if you post this in the plugin's support forum. Third party plugins are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @bravokeyl - thanks for your reply. we do hardly get proper responses in plugin support page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look for `tel` in the plugin gives me this check for telephone numbers:

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '%^[+]?[0-9()/ -]*$%', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

Using the above function the plugin is validating whether the user input is a valid `tel` or not. So the above regex is the one that is used for validation.